# How does 'subexpression' work in "replace-match" function in emacs

Tags: emacs, elisp

When reading the description of "replace-match" function in Emacs I can't understand what is the 'subexpression' attribute and how it should be used? For example in
`(replace-match (format-time-string writestamp-format (current-time)) t t nil 1)`
what does the '1' mean?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [the manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Replacing-Match.html):

> If subexp is non-nil, that says to replace just subexpression number
>   subexp of the regexp that was matched, not the entire match. For
>   example, after matching ‘foo (ba*r)’, calling replace-match with 1
>   as subexp means to replace just the text that matched ‘(ba*r)’.

You will need to understand subexpressions of a regular expression first, to understand this feature: By delimiting a part of a regular expression with braces, you can group it and then access those groups. This is very useful if you want to reuse parts of the match in the replacement text when doing a `query-replace-regex`. This is simply the way it works here.

Imagine you want to replace every occurence of `bar(SOMETHING)` with `foo(SOMETHING)`. So you first match with `bar(\([^)]*\))` (this means every character besides `)` is allowed within the parentheses and that our first subexpression is everything that is matched between `\(` and `\)`.

Answer (score 2):

I googled "emacs subexpression" and the [first hit](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Simple-Match-Data.html) explains it:

> Recall that the subexpressions of a regular expression are those expressions grouped with escaped parentheses, ‘\(...\)’. The countth subexpression is found by counting occurrences of ‘\(’ from the beginning of the whole regular expression. The first subexpression is numbered 1, the second 2, and so on.

For example, if you do a regular expression search for `\([a-z]+\) \([0-9]+\)`, then the first subexpression contains the `[a-z]+` part, and the second subexpression contains the `[0-9]+` part.